# PHP Gráficas con jqplot, al convertir a imagen se traba el explorador de internet

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy trabajando con PHP (XAMPP) y estoy haciendo gráficas con jqplot, mis gráficas funcionan muy bien, pero cuando quiero convertir la gráfica a imagen funciona  bien en el servidor local, pero en otra PC se traba el explorador de internet, alguien sabrá por que? o alguien a hecho algo parecido con éxito?
[image: En el server si funciona convertirlo a imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré una solución, para todos aquellos que tengan este problema, les comento que hay que actualizar una librería js `jquery/jquery.jqplot.js`, la cual puedes localizar [aquí](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqPlot). Por otro lado es importante que todas las librerías y archivos que necesita `jqplot`, deben de estar sin excepción, si te basas en un ejemplo podrás hacerlo de manera correcta. [Este es un ejemplo](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html).

Cada tipo de gráfica requiere un archivo render `xxxxx_Renderer.min.js`. Te muestro algunos de los archivos que se necesitan para diferentes gráficas, puedes poner todas las librerías juntas no ocasionan conflicto:

En el Head

```
   <link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comple/jquery.jqplot.css" />
    <link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comple/jquery.jqplot.min.css" /><!-- Se Agrego -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comple/examples.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="comple/shCoreDefault.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="comple/shThemejqPlot.min.css" />
```

</script>

</script>

Y en el la parte posterior de las gráficas, dentro de un DIV

```
 <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="comple/shCore.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="comple/shBrushJScript.min.js">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="comple/shBrushXml.min.js"></script>

 <script class="include" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jqplot.json2.js"></script>
 <!-- Additional plugins go here -->

 <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>

<!-- <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>-->
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="comple/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

<!-- End additional plugins -->


</div>  

<!-- Termina el DIV -->

 <script type="text/javascript" src="comple/example.js"></script>
```

Con esto puedes convertir tus gráficas en imagen fuera de tu servidor, para que no se trabe la pagina al quererlo hacer.

Hay un inconveniente y estoy trabajando en eso. Cuando se abre la pantalla de imagen, se esta desfasando, se ve un poco más grande y no se ve toda la imagen en el recuadro, espero resolverlo, si alguien tiene la solución, le agradezco compartir.

Saludos